# Send/receive email using Pidgin (GAIM)?

Tags: pidgin

Can I send and receive email using Pidgin/GAIM? I realize I'll need a 
special incoming address that "redirects to GAIM" (ie, encodes 
incoming email in Jabber format + sends it to a Jabber server).

Other than that, it seems easy (though not trivial) to setup something 
like this. Has anyone done so?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because you don't have receiving address can be recognized by e-mail clients.

Even if you did that your messages will recognized by spam killer as scam e-mail

Comment: I could set the sending address as "barry@gaim.barrycarter.info" and then setup the SMTP server for gaim.barrycarter.info to pipe to a program that sends the email to the jabber server.

Comment: Do you successfully could send a message to gmail.com e-mail address for instance?

Comment: Sure, but gmail email and gmail chat are 2 separate things.